# Not able to record power bi embedding web application in JMeter .app.powerbi.com is throwing error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am using Apache JMeter 5.3.  I am facing issue when my application points connects to https://app.powerbi.com using proxy. I tried using behind the proxy, it didnt help.

Please help me with the error message

Error Message:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: app.powerbi.com
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:401)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:930)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:641)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1281)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:234)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr` you're trying to get the IP address for app.powerbi.com using [IPv6 implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)

And according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6 the website doesn't support IPv6

[image]

You might want to [restrict Java TCP/IP stack to IPv4 only](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) by adding the next line to *system.properties* file:

```
java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the property.

Alternatively you can consider using an alternative approach to recording: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), using it you won't have to worry about proxies, certificates, protocol versions, etc.